# Change the Way UTCString is generated

Tags: javascript, api, unix-timestamp, utc

I converted a unix timestamp from an API to a more readable date using this code:

`var newTimeStamp = new Date();
  newTimeStamp.setTime(date*1000);
  date = newTimeStamp.toUTCString();`

(date is a variable I set for the date data coming in from the API which I reassigned to this new format).

That generated the date like this:

```
Wed, 11 May 2016 16:00:00 GMT
Thu, 12 May 2016 16:00:00 GMT
Fri, 13 May 2016 16:00:00 GMT
Sat, 14 May 2016 16:00:00 GMT
```

I really only need the day of the week, day and month. Is there an easy way to limit this data?

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language you're using.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using javascript/jquery.

Comment: Consider using `Moment.js` or `Date.js`.  Javascript has no native support for arbitrary date formats, and writing your own is not a good use of dev time.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first parts from the date like `Wed, 11 May` from the UTC string, then you can use the regular expression to do that.

```js
var regex = /(\w{3}, \d{2} \w{3})(?:.+)/;
var date = new Date();
var outputStr = "";
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1 )
  var dateStr = date.toUTCString();
  dateStr = dateStr.replace(regex, "$1");
  
  outputStr += dateStr + '\n';
}

document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML = outputStr;
```

```html
<pre id="output">
  </pre>
```

Comment: How can I edit that regex code so that it automatically generates the day of the week, right now when I put that code through my loop, every day is getting displayed as Wednesday, 11 May

Comment: You need complete day name `Wednesday` instead of `Wed` ?

Comment: No, sorry. The code your wrote prints the same day over and over again. I already have it in a for loop, but it's not working the way I want it to. It's looping the same date, I want it to increment by a day each time.

Comment: Updated the code, check it.